# How to select a column using a mouse, in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to use `SHIFT + drag mouse` to select a column of text in VIM?  If so, how?

Comment: http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20060727_145450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Vi was written for restricted non-graphical environments and doesn't even assume the presence of arrow keys. Depending on what shell / terminal you're using, you may be able to use your operating system's mouse and text selection facilities to do what you need. Just bear in mind they're not native to Vim.

Use Ctrl+V and J/K [or up/down arrows if you have them ;)] to move the highlighted selection.

Hit Y to copy the column and p to paste it somewhere else.

Comment: Note that in Windows (with `behave mswin` in your vimrc) Ctrl+V is replaced with Ctrl+Q.

Comment: If you're going to use J/K then the mouse might be better :)  Use CTRL+V and then some more intelligent motion to get where you need to go.  Read `:help motion.txt` and I would also look at the EasyMotion Vim utility (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).

Answer (score 4):

At least in Windows, you can Alt-drag.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK alt-dragging works everywhere (on Mac it's option-dragging).

But I'm with Andrew and Kit... keep your friggin' hands off that damned mouse! :)

Comment: Alt-dragging moves the window on Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually, it moves windows on **Gnome**.

Comment: A true ninja will use all input devices at his disposal.

Comment: Actually, a true ninja can't be seen to use input devices.  But, I would reword what you've said - A true ninja will use all _efficient_ input devices at his disposal.  In this case (_in this case_) the mouse does not fit that description.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended. You can use Ctrl+V to highlight a block.